# Как изменить AlertDialog window android?

Tags: java, android

Я создаю новое приложение и хочу переопределить системную `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`.

У меня проблема с изменением окна `AlertDialog`.
Я не могу изменить цвет горизонтальной линии между названием и телом (синий по умолчанию). Пожалуйста, подскажите какой атрибут определяет его цвет.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setNegativeButton("не", null)
            .setTitle("Выход")
            .setMessage("Уверен")
            .setPositiveButton("да",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельный layout c нужной вам разметкой(назначьте какой надо цвет для любого элемента), а дальше ее "раздуйте" в алерт диалоге:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddOnlineOrderActivity.this);
View View = li.inflate(R.layout.some_dialog, null);
b.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();   
        }
    });
AlertDialog a = b.create();
a.show();
```